# Spans with display:none is not showing the space bars in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, contenteditable

We had a use case where some spans with `display:none` is added to our content editable div.

So when the user somehow lands on the span and tries to add content, the space bars are getting added inside the span, thereby not showing up in the UI. All other characters are working fine. The issue is only with the space.

This seems to be a Firefox only issue. Chrome is working fine.

Was able to reproduce the issue using this jsfiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/senths/ehLp86zy/3/ (click b/w hello & world and try to add space)

[image: Fiddle demo]

Firefox Version Used: 91.8.0esr (64-bit)

Is this behaviour expected in Firefox?

Any lead is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confused by the other answer, to the best of my knowledge the solution here is the exact opposite. If you add `contenteditable="false"` to the `span` it will prevent spaces getting added to the hidden `span`.

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div contenteditable="true" id="editor2">
    hello<span style="display: none" id="dummy_bkm" contenteditable="false">&nbsp;</span>world
  </div>
</div>
```

To understand what's happening try inserting a space in the below code (without the `display: none` and without the `contenteditable="false"`

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div contenteditable="true" id="editor2">
    hello<span style="background: green;" id="dummy_bkm" >&nbsp;</span>world
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The fix is working fine. Thanks for the workaround @DavidMulder . I'm still not clear about why the issue was only happening with white spaces. Any idea why?

Comment: @Senthil Check the edit to the answer. The space is getting inserted into the `span`. There is a fair bit of weird behavior like this in contenteditable elements. I work on an editor using contenteditable rendering and we completely disregard the browser's native insertion handling (we `preventDefault` the `beforeInput`).

Comment: Yeah, the space getting added inside `display:none` span was the issue. But my question was, why this not happening for characters other than space?

Comment: @Senthil Both Chrome and Firefox 'keep spaces together' in the span, the difference in behavior is that Firefox doesn't care about the rendering visibility of the span. (Just for fun: add `visibility: hidden` to the span in the second example and behold the mess that is `contentEditable` rendering :D )

Answer (score 0):

If you set contenteditable="true" inside the span tag this will work how (I believe) you intent it to in Firefox.

There is a know reported bug in Firefox that is 4 years old. Information about that is at: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1489481

Comment: This is not the case here right. The bug talks about an inline element inside two elements with `contenteditable=false` and `display: inline-block`. Here the span is already inside a content editable div.